# Using Spring Boot profiles on external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, devops

I am looking for a solution to the problem, which is that having an external Tomcat server with several different applications (war),
I would like to use application Spring Profile (dev, prod) to choose application.properties for a given profile.
To avoid keeping the database configuration in the git repository, I didn't store in the application
application.properties, but I kept them in the $catalina.base directory, where in common.loader
I indicated the path to this directory. This worked until I started deploying several different applications. Then each of them began to use
from the same datasource. One solution is to keep the application.properties in Jenkins and directly in Jobie indicating which one to use,
but I am not sure if this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Create a separate instance of tomcat (using same tomcat binary) and place application.properties in instance's classpath. As classpath is separate for every instance, applications don't refer to same application.properties file. Refer to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/run-configure-multiple-instance-in-a-single-tomcat) article to see how to create multiple instances on same tomcat server.

**Option 2:** Create JNDI datasource on tomcat server and use it in your application to access database. This way, should you choose to, same datasource can be shared across different related applications and/or modules. For more information on how to create JNDI datasource in Tomcat, refer to this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)